# Going back from a full size opened image to the latest site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So, i had a little problem in my course homework.
As a part of it, we need to make a gallery, so I thought I would make a simple but efficient one. I have 2 set of pictures, one is the original, big one, and one is small, **200x200px big**.

The question, how could I give a back button from the opened, full size image, so it would navigate back to the gallery?
I just use this:

```
<a href="image.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="image_small.jpg" alt="IMAGE" align="right" /></a>
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Close the window or the tab. The site is still there

Comment: Linking to the image file means the user has to use the browser's back button (or hotkey, or mouse's back button) to go back. The only way to include your own button with the image is to link to another HTML doc that shows the image and your button.

Comment: so I should create then a tons of new pages just to put it in? Sad:( thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this : 
add a new page is needed :

image.html

```
<html>
 <body><img onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);" src="image.jgp" alt="IMAGE" align="center"/></body>
</html>
```

your link principal page :

```
<a href="image.html" target="_blank"><img src="image_small.jpg" alt="IMAGE" align="right" /></a>
```

Create file image.html, put in the same folder and test gl.